# dynamically adding an array to a resource in run time

Tags: c#, odata, restier

I have a custom `ODataResourceSerializer` which under some conditions adds new properties to a resource, that works perfectly.

I am trying to add a new simple int[] property

the resource is a dynamic resource that is registered at runtime and does not have these properties on the model.

this code

```
case TypeX tx:

  propertiesToReturn.Add(new ODataProperty()
     {
        Name = "TypeX",
        Value = new ODataCollectionValue()
        {
           Items = new int[] {1,2,3}
        }
     });
```

gives me whrn the resource is sent to the `ODataJsonLightPropertySerializer.WriteCollectionProperty`

> A type named 'System.Int32[]' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type.

and when trying to add the value directly to the odata property

```
new ODataProperty()
{
    Value = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }   
}
```

I get on add

> An ODataPrimitiveValue was instantiated with a value of type 'System.Int32[]'. ODataPrimitiveValue can only wrap values which can be represented as primitive EDM types

I tried adding int[] to the model builder
I tried adding a type to the ODataCollectionValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved using `ODataUntypedValue` and serializing the value according to the return type "XML/JSON"

for example

```
Value = new ODataUntypedValue
{                            
    RawValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })
}
```